# Extracting solutions from SDE

Tags: plotting, time-series, stochastic-calculus

I have an SDE system which I solve using

```
proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]kai1[z] == 
    0.0001*I*kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w1[z] + 
     I*kai1 [z] \[DifferentialD]w2[z] - 
     I*kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w3[z] + kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w4[z] +
      kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]z,
   \[DifferentialD]kai2[z] == 
    I*kai2[z] \[DifferentialD]w1[z] + .1*I*
      kai2[z] \[DifferentialD]w2[z] - 
     I*kai4[z] \[DifferentialD]w3[z] + kai4[z] \[DifferentialD]w4[z] +
      kai2[z] \[DifferentialD]z,
   \[DifferentialD]kai3[z] == 
    I*kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w1[z] - 
     I*kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w2[z] + 
     I*kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w3[z] + kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w4[z] +
      kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]z,
   \[DifferentialD]kai4[z] == 
    I*kai4[z] \[DifferentialD]w1[z] + 
     I*kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]w2[z] - 
     I*kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w3[z] + kai3[z] \[DifferentialD]w4[z] +
      kai1[z] \[DifferentialD]z}, {kai1[z], kai2[z], kai3[z], 
   kai4[z]}, {{kai1, kai2, kai3, kai4}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}, 
  z, {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   w3 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   w4 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}]
```

and then

```
sol = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 1, 0.01}]
```

I can then plot the solution via

```
ListLinePlot[Abs[sol]^2 , PlotRange -> All]
```

But how can I extract just one of the solutions, ie kai1,2,3,4?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `sol` from your code, I'd do it like this:

```
data = sol["Path"];
munger[{x_, y_}] := {x, Abs[#]^2} & /@ y
{path1, path2, path3, path4} = Transpose[munger /@ data];
ListLinePlot[{path1, path2, path3, path4}, PlotLegends -> {kai1, kai2, kai3, kai4}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

`sol` is `TemporalData` so you can extract the data from it

```
abs = Abs[sol]^2;
data = abs["Paths"][[1, 2 ;;]];
split = Table[{#[[1]], #[[2, i]]} & /@ data, {i, 1, 4}];
```

`split` has 4 elements corresponding to the `x, y` values for each function.

```
ListLinePlot /@ split // GraphicsRow
```

[image]